# Drawing Bode Plot from transfer function

Tags: control-system, bode-plot

I have the following question

[image]

I need to Draw the Bode Plot,so i need to find Magnitude and Phase Angles for a Frquency.I understand that i need to susbstitude `S=jW`(W>Omega) as per this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cwczVhTKiE

But in my question that denominator is not of the from (1+xxS)(1+XXS) so how should i proceed.Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

"*denominator is not of the from (1+xxS)(1+XXS)*"

If you like such a form (and I would agree with you for solving the present task), you have nothing to do than to find the complex roots (s1 and s2) of the denominator equation D(s)=0. Then you can write **D(s)=(1-s1)(1-s2)**.

**EDIT:** Regarding the three other questions - I have some problems to understand the meaning. Stability parameters are defined for systems with feedback only. For all stability calculations we need the loop gain. Here, we have a given transfer function - and that´s all we have. Hence, these three questions make no sense, unless a feedback loop is shown.

Comment: Do you mean by using the equation http://img.sparknotes.com/figures/A/a28868a2f5deab01f6e8c7727c2ee7a4/latex_img44.gif

Comment: Yes, of course. D(s) is a simple quadratic equation to be solved applying the classical methods.

Comment: I got (1+.000246)(1+.000246).. please let me know if im right.

Comment: No - that´s not looking good. A double real pole? It´s a simple quadratic equation to be solved!

Comment: Will solve it again..then..

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this: -

\$s^2+ s + 1\$ becomes \$1-\omega^2 +j\omega\$

In other words you have a real and imaginery part. I've just substituted s with jw remembering that \$j^2\$ = -1.

Multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate (\$1-\omega^2 -j\omega\$) to bring all the terms of j to the numerator. Denominator becomes \$(1-\omega^2)^2 +\omega^2\$ and as you can see there are no "j" terms.

Is this enough of a hint to get you to a solution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but it seems the way in which the video proceeds need the numerator is specific form (1+xxS)(1+XXS).. ie:1+something.. Im a computer science guy.. dont know much about Bode Plot..

Comment: Do you know how to solve the roots of a quadratic equation?